# Custom Format for wmic output in BATCH (CMD)

Tags: batch-file, format, output, wmic, custom-formatting

How to put a custom format for wmic output in batch ?

before everything to start, i wan't to say that i'm not english and that my text will be bad lmao

> Hello, i'm a batch beginner and i would like to make a custom output format for wmic

Exemple :

`1# Memory Name : Corsair`

`2# Memory Name : Kingston`

`3# Memory Name : Corsair`

`4# Memory Name : Kingston`

the problem is that my code will show only the latest memory name
like i have 4 chip of memory but it will only show me one of them

Exemple :

`1# Memory Name : Corsair`

but i don't really know how would i be able to do what i want with a custom output format

if you need the actual code :

```
wmic memorychip get manufacturer /value | findstr /r /v "^$" > manufacturer & wmic memorychip get capacity /value | findstr /r /v "^$" > capacity & set /p manufacturer=<manufacturer&set /p capacity=<capacity
set memory%manufacturer%&set memory%capacity%&del manufacturer&del capacity

echo Memory : %memorymanufacturer% %memorycapacity%
```

Comment: Please show me the results from the command: `wmic memorychip get manufacturer /value`

Comment: @Gerhard https://prnt.sc/UvIiMMV4zeiK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you do not `set` variables, you're probably not going to get much more compact than this:

```
@echo off & set cnt=0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%i in ('wmic memorychip get capacity^,manufacturer') do for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%%i") do (
    set /a cnt+=1
    set "cap!cnt!=%%a"
    set "man!cnt!=%%b"
)
for /L %%r in (1,1,%cnt%) do echo(# %%r Manufacturer: !man%%r:  =!   Capacity: !cap%%r: =!
```

If however you do not set the variables and simply use the metavariables, it can be much more compact:

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%i in ('wmic memorychip get capacity^,manufacturer') do for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%%i") do echo Manufacturer: %%b Capacity %%a
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use my [wmiClass.bat program](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=10384&p=66414#p66401) instead of the standard wmic.exe command.

```
@if (@CodeSegment == @Batch) ( @then

Show properties of a WMI class.

wmiClass [/NS:namespace] [*|class [*|property ...] [/WHERE:clause]]

  /NS:namespace     Specify the namespace, defaults to \root\cimv2.
  class             Show property names of the given class.
  class property    Show values of given properties of the class or alias.
  /WHERE:clause     Clause to select property records to process.

List names of all WMI classes
   wmiClass *

List all properties of the given class
   wmiClass Win32_LocalTime

Show values of all properties of the class
   wmiClass Win32_LocalTime *

Show specific values
   wmiClass Win32_LocalTime Year Month Day

Show values from a wmic.exe alias
   wmiClass OS LocalDateTime

Show selected records
   wmiClass Win32_Process ProcessID Name /where:"Name='cmd.exe'"

@endHelp

Developed and written by Antonio Perez Ayala

First version of this program is a modification of wmiCollection function
included in FindRepl.bat version 2.2 program released on 2014
https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697&p=38121#p38121

- 2022/02/21: version 1
- 2022/02/23: version 1.1: /NS option added
- 2022/02/27: version 1.3: significant code rewrite based on version 1.2 written by siberia-man
                           https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=66294#p66294
                           "*" and /WHERE options added. Auto-search for alias added
)

@echo off

if "%~1" == "" (
   for /F "skip=2 tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%~F0"') do (
      if "%%b" == "@endHelp" goto :EOF
      echo/%%b
   )
)

CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" %*
goto :EOF


@end


// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393741(v=vs.85).aspx

var args = WScript.Arguments.Unnamed,
    opts = WScript.Arguments.Named,
    wmi  = GetObject( "WinMgmts:" + (opts.Exists("NS")?opts.Item("NS"):"") ),
    clas = args.Item(0),  collection, fetch;

function enumerate (collection,fetch) {
    var r = [];
    for ( var e = new Enumerator(collection); !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext() ) {
        r.push(fetch(e.item()));
    }
    return r;
}


if ( clas == "*" ) {  // List all classes in this NameSpace; ignore properties, if any
   collection = wmi.SubclassesOf();
   fetch = function(el) { return el.Path_.Class; };

} else if ( args.length == 1 ) {  // No properties given: list all property names of given class
   collection = wmi.Get(clas).Properties_;
   fetch = function(el) { return el.Name; };

} else {  // Show property values
   var where = opts.Exists('WHERE') ? " where "+opts.Item('WHERE') : "";
   collection = wmi.ExecQuery( "Select * from " + clas + where );

   if ( (new Enumerator(collection)).atEnd() ) {  // No class found: check the alias
      var alias = GetObject("WinMgmts:\\root\\cli");
      collection = alias.ExecQuery("Select Target from Msft_CliAlias where FriendlyName='"+clas+"'");
      var e = new Enumerator(collection);
      if ( e.atEnd() ) {
         WScript.Stderr.WriteLine("Class or alias not exists: "+clas);
         WScript.Quit(1);
      }
      clas = e.item().Target.substr(14);
      collection = wmi.ExecQuery( "Select * from " + clas + where );
   }

   var prop = [];
   if ( args.Item(1) == "*" ) {  // Show all properties of this class; ignore rest, if any
      prop = enumerate( wmi.Get(clas).Properties_, function(el) { return el.Name; } );
   } else {  // Show given properties
      for ( var i = 1; i < args.length; i++ ) { prop.push(args.Item(i)); }
   }

   fetch = function(el) {
              var r = [];
              for ( var i = 0; i < prop.length; i++ ) {
                 var n = prop[i];
                 r.push(n + "=" + el[n]);
              }
              return r.join('\n');
           }
   ;

}

WScript.StdOut.WriteLine(enumerate(collection,fetch).join('\n'));
```

Try this:

```
wmiClass memorychip manufacturer capacity
```

If this command show just one result, then there is not a standard method to get the data of your 4 memory chips...

If the 4 names appear, then just do this:

```
set "i=0"
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmiClass memorychip manufacturer') do (
   set /A i+=1
   echo !i!# Memory Name : %%a
)
```

Comment: yes..... but no, i would like to have everything in one script and something really compact

Comment: just replace the `for` line in Aacini's last code block with `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic memorychip get manufacturer /value^|find "="') do (`

Comment: thanks! but now, how can i get all the information ? like:
.
.
#1 Memory : {NAME} ; {CAPACITY}hz

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this 'more compact' single line command would work better for you:

```sh
@For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe MemoryChip Get BankLabel^, Manufacturer 2^>NUL') Do @For /F "Tokens=2,*" %%H In ("%%G") Do @Echo %%H# Memory Name : %%I
```